# How to fire event on specific image rotation?

Tags: ios, swift, web-applications, uiimageview, geolocation

I'm using this code to align the `myCompass`-ImageView to the current device heading. *(Rotate the image to point in North direction -->**it's a compass**)*

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    let Heading = newHeading.trueHeading.toRadians

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.myCompass.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Heading))
    }
}
```

This code is working quiet fine but as you can see I've added a small animation so that the rotation of the IMageView doesn't looks that ugly.

**Problem:** Now I want to fire an event if the `myCompass`-view is pointing exactly to **the north pole**.

```
if (Heading > -4 && Heading < 4) {
  event()
}
```

- --> Because of the animation I can not check the `heading` because it could take about `0.5 seconds` till the needle exactly points to North.
- --> I can not check the heading & add a `0.5-delay` because the heading could change within this `0.5 seconds` again

---

SO to my question:

**Is it possible to listen for some kind of specific rotation event of an ImageView?**

**Or is there some more elegant way to get a result like this?**

Maybe something like this pseudo code:

```
myCompass.onOrientation(rotationAngleMin: 5, rotationAngleMax: -5, event) 
func event() {
  print("hurray")
}
```

Comment: have you tried key-value observing?

Comment: Could you please provide some example code? @AgentSmith

Answer (score 0):

You can try key-value observing on transform property of you image by:

```
myCompass.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "transform", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
```

and then observe it in the following method

```
override func addObserver(_ observer: NSObject, forKeyPath keyPath: String, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [], context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "transform" {
        // Check your updates here

    }
}
```

Hope it works!!